# how to use a variable in the BEGIN block in awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I try to run a one-line command like this

```
touch ./py.py; awk 'BEGIN{print FILENAME}' ./py.py
```

and expect to get the result `./py.py` but only get a blank line. However, if I do it without a `BEGIN` block, it works:

```
touch ./py.py; awk '{print FILENAME}' ./py.py
```

It seems that the `FILENAME` variable is not available in the `BEGIN` block. Why is that? How can I use that variable in the `BEGIN` block?

Comment: What is it that you need to do that you need the filename in the `BEGIN` block? There is probably a technique for accomplishing what your [real goal is](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Awk can process multiple files in one invocation (e.g. `awk '{whatever}' file1 file2 file3`). The BEGIN block is executed when awk starts, before it opens the first file, not at the beginning of each file (END blocks are similar). One could possibly argue that extending awk to have per-file BEGIN/END hooks might be useful, but they don't exist in any current version of awk/nawk/gawk that I've used...

Comment: GNU AWK 4 (`gawk`) has `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize with the benefit of hindsight:

- In `gawk (GNU awk) 4` or higher, using `BEGINFILE` instead of `BEGIN` ensures that `FILENAME` is defined; note, however, that `BEGINFILE`, as the name suggests, is called for *every* input file.
- In other `awk` variants, where only `BEGIN` is offered, **`FILENAME` is not yet defined** at that point, because, by design, *input-file processing has not begun yet*. (By contrast, `FILENAME` *does* have a value in the `END` block, namely the *last* file processed.)

**Workaround**:

You can  gain access to the **filename arguments** passed to awk via the built-in argument `ARGV`, where `ARGV[1]` reports the 1st filename argument, `ARGV[2]` the 2nd, and so on.

- Note that options and implied stdin input do *not* count, so with implicit `stdin` input `ARGV[1]` will be an *empty string*.
- By contrast, pseudo filenames that act as variable assignments *do* count (e.g., `VAR=10`).

Thus, assuming no pseudo filenames, `ARGV[1]` in the `BEGIN` block is the equivalent of `FILENAME` in later blocks while the [first] file is being processed.

**Caveat re implicit use of `stdin`**: `BSD awk` (e.g., on OSX) reports implicit `stdin` input also as an empty string in `FILENAME` (in later blocks), whereas `mawk` and `gawk` report `"-"`.
All 3 variants, however, support *explicit* `stdin` input by passing `-` as a filename argument, in which case `FILENAME` returns `"-"` in all 3 variants.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that FILENAME isn't available in BEGIN block of awk. As a matter of fact awk doesn't start processing input file in the BEGIN block hence this internal variable is not set. Even this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print;}' ./file
```

will not print anything from file.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I have no idea what's the deeper sense of this, I could still come up with a hack. I would not call it a "solution" though. Still, it was a nice way of passing time. ;)

This is one of the original working one-liners:

```
touch ./py.py; awk '{print FILENAME}' ./py.py
```

For that, you have to know that `awk` **physically** checks whether the file exists on the media. Hence, had we attempted something like this:

```
awk '{print FILENAME}' ./py2.py
```

`awk` would have bailed out with:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `./py2.py' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Alright. So *if* we're in a BEGIN block (therefore getting files ignored as arguments), we will have to *simulate* this behavior as if the argument behind the `awk` line *were* a file, via the sneaky approach with the `awk`-builtin `ARGV[]`array, e. g. like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {$0 = ARGV[1]; if ((getline <$0) == -1) print "ERROR: File not found: " $0; else print ARGV[1]}' ./py.py
```

This will give the result:

```
./py.py
```

So far, so good. Now why not do deliberately with a file we don't have on the physical media:

```
awk 'BEGIN {$0 = ARGV[1]; if ((getline <$0) == -1) print "ERROR: File not found: " $0; else print ARGV[1]}' ./py2.py
```

will result in

```
ERROR: File not found: ./py2.py
```

So we're physically checking files for existence (like `awk` does with `FILENAME`in non-`BEGIN` blocks) and spitting out an error if the file does not exist.
Rather pointless IMO, but---alas, if we always had to question how sensible a solution actually is, we'd need the span of a lifetime for it, especially in politics. :)